# A specific route is missed from the build folder when using Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

In my Vue.js application, a specific route `/embed/contact-form/:id` is not included in the build folder by Vite. The page loaded in localhost but not in production (Vercel).

Here's the [link](https://github.com/roopeshsn/embed/blob/b14c47ec9d7bb210523b74e96e05caed9c6455e1/src/router/index.js#L63) to the project route file.